# Prevent form action from being followed by robots

Tags: seo, typo3, powermail

Is there a way to prevent robots to follow form actions? I get errors like this:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1298012500: Required argument "form" is not set for Tx_Powermail_Controller_FormsController->create.
```

This cause robots try to follow this links via GET request.

I'm using the powermail extension and this will use the fluid ViewHelper `f:form`. I tried to remove the action parameter, but this parameter will appear anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent malicious bots from trying to access that action. You can only hope to make friendly bots ignore it.

To do that, try to add the attribute `rel="nofollow"` to the form tag. It tells robots that you don't want the link to be followed. It would look like this in fluid:

```
<f:form [...] additionalAttributes="{rel: 'nofollow'}">...</f:form>
```

I'm not sure that it'll actually prevents bots from calling the action.

A (possibly not applicable) alternative way would be to add a `<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow"/>` to the pages `<head>`. (Maybe replace `index` with `noindex`.)

Comment: This is a good hint! I will try this. I hope the bot will respect this attribute :)

Comment: `rel="nofollow"` does not apply to forms, only `<a>` tags.